# Associative array from a database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

On my models I try to write a php model that will get me a associative array from a database. But I don't quite know how to approach this.
So after I execute this SQL query:

```
SELECT balance_events.weight,balance_events.added_date,
       balance_entries.mid FROM balance_events, balance_entries 
WHERE balance_entries.added_date BETWEEN '2016-08-02' AND '2016-08-03' 
  AND balance_entries.ptid =12 
  AND balance_entries.beid = balance_events.id
```

I will get this table:

[image]

And from that table I want to extract a asociative array that it will look like this:

```
count = ['13'=>1, '6'=>4, '16'=>3, '4'=>3]
```

where `'mid'=>number` of how many times that `mid` can be found in the table.
ex. `mid '13'=>1` cause you can found it only once.

I think that I will have to use SQL COUNT function, but how I can aggregate all of this in a PHP model in codeigniter? I know how to configure controller and view, but I don't know how to actually do the actual php model that will get me the desired array.

Comment: u want to write query in your model ???

Comment: Yes, there you handle the actual data that you send in the controller then view, right?

Comment: correct me, if i am wrong, 1) you want to convert this query in CI model etc, 2) your expected result. IN LAST, explore `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query may help you ,

```
$result = $this->db->select('balance_events.weight,balance_events.added_date,COUNT(balance_entries.mid) as mid_count')
                   ->from('balance_events, balance_entries')
                   ->where('balance_entries.added_date BETWEEN "2016-08-02" AND "2016-08-03" ')
                   ->where('balance_entries.ptid','12')
                   ->where('balance_entries.beid','balance_events.id')
                   ->group_by('balance_entries.mid')
                   ->get();

return $result->result_array();
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/test.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/test/application/views/test.php
Line: 12
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/www/html/test/application/controllers/Test.php
Line: 9
Function: view

File: /var/www/html/test/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: This is error that I get, in the view I just echo the var from the controller.

Comment: You need to use    print_r() instead of echo

Comment: I will get now a empty array: Array ( )

Comment: Try to print query and run it on phpmyadmin 
and see what will you get through query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would create this in SQL but since you tagged php, I wrote a function that would do just this.

```
<?php
  $query = array(array("mid"=>13), array("mid"=>2), array("mid"=>13), array("mid" =>6), array("mid" => 13), array("mid" => 6));

  function createMidArray($queryResult){
      $returnArray = array();
      foreach ($queryResult as $qr){
          $returnArray[$qr['mid']]++;   
      }
  return $returnArray;
}

  print_r(createMidArray($query));

?>
```

The output of this was `Array ( [13] => 3 [2] => 1 [6] => 2 )` which matches up to my inputted $query (which is a 2D array). I'm expecting the output of your query is stored in a similar array, but with more data and keys

Comment: OP has a query, I'm using the results from his query to generate this new array which is what he needed

Comment: from question: *but how I can agregate all of this in a PHP model in codeigniter? I know how to configure controler and view, but I don't know how to actually do the actual php model that will get me the desired array.*

Comment: `but I don't know how to actually do the actual php model that will get me the desired array`  Isn't this the answer?

Comment: i think mixer of both answers is a solution. maybe